# Why do hydroxyl ions migrate towards the anode in a Bacon Cell?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, electrolysis

Why do hydroxyl ions in a Bacon cell migrate towards the anode? Is it because of the relative concentration of the different ions in the set-up? According to the set-up of the bacon cell, the anode is negatively charged, thus would actually repel the incoming negative hydroxyl ions, but does not seem to do so. Please let me know if any further details are required.

I read on a wikipedia link explaining cathodes that this kind of migration (i.e negative ions towards a negative electrode) is in fact typical of discharging cells, chemical energy being the driving force behind this sort of "uphill" motion. Could someone please elaborate on this?

[image: Image of a Bacon Cell attached]

Comment: Well, they are anions and this is anode...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alkaline_fuel_cell aka Bacon Cell

Comment: @Mithoron-Yes,but the anode is negatively charged here hence the confusion.

Comment: @Martin-An alkaline fuel cell is also known as a Bacon Cell.I have added more details and an image which i hope would help readers understand the reason for my asking the question.

Comment: @MaxW-Thanks for the link.I did go through it but it still did not help understanding the reason for the migration of negative hydroxyl ions towards the negatively charged anode.I have added more details to the question.Would appreciate any sort of help here.